# Converting date from string with dateformatter for tableView's titleForHeader but getting nil error

Tags: ios, swift

I have a selected Date from a collectionView calendar that I want to format as a date and set as the header for my tableView in the same View Controller. However, I get an error when I try to format it and set it as a header title.

Here's my code with error:

```
var selectedDate = Date!
let formatter: DateFormatter = {
    let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
    dateFormatter.timeZone = Calendar.current.timeZone
    dateFormatter.locale = Calendar.current.locale
    dateFormatter.dateFormat = "yyyy MM dd"
    return dateFormatter } ()


func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, titleForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> String? {
        formatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss +zzzz"
        let dateForTableViewHeader = formatter.string(from: selectedDate) // Thread 1: Fatal error: Unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value
        return dateForTableViewHeader
    }
```

For the error, my console prints: selectedDate  Date?   nil none

If I change it to all to only this line

```
return "\(String(describing: selectedDate))"
```

then it prints the selected Date as the title header: Optional(2018-09-25 07:00:00 +0000)

I want to convert this to a date format like September 25, 2018. If it prints the value of selectedDate directly, why do I get a nil error for when I try to convert it to a different date format?

Comment: Clearly from the error, `selectedDate` is `nil`. If it's not supposed to be nil (why else would you make it an implicitly unwrapped optional if it wasn't supposed to be nil), then your question needs to be about why it is nil and not about date formatting.

Comment: Unrelated - do not use a fixed date format to show a date to a user. Use a date style so the date appears in a format that the user expects.

Comment: @rmaddy Thank you. also found your site page about this via google search. After I figure out  the nil issue, I will implement datestyle

Answer (score 0):

```
import Foundation

var selectedDate = Date()
let formatter: DateFormatter = {
     let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
     dateFormatter.dateStyle = .full
     dateFormatter.timeZone = Calendar.current.timeZone
     dateFormatter.locale = Calendar.current.locale
     return dateFormatter

 } ()


 func printDate() -> String{
    print("selected date \(selectedDate)")
    formatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd"
    let newDate = formatter.string(from: selectedDate)
    return newDate
 }

 printDate()
```

Comment: Hi Ashish. That looks like it was a typo on my end. I do have it as what you have recommended. I updated my code in the post too. It still returns the same nil value. Anything else I can look at?

Comment: var selectedDate = Date! this line is a problem it needs to be either var selectedDate:Date! or var selectedDate = Date(),